# How to change background-color of a "li" if I put the cursor in an input field inside the "li"?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to set the `background-color` of the `li` when I put the cursor in a or b or c? 
I have this list with 100 records and I want the hole row ("li") to show up in another color so it gets more easy to work with the list.

```
<li id=recordsArray_1>
 <form medthod=post name=fr_1 id=fr_1>
  <input type=text name=a> <input type=text name=b> <input type=text name=c>
  <input type=submit name=b_1 value=ok>
 </form>
</li>

<li id=recordsArray_2>
 <form medthod=post name=fr_2 id=fr_2>
  <input type=text name=a> <input type=text name=b> <input type=text name=c>
  <input type=submit name=b_2 value=ok>
 </form>
</li>

<li id=recordsArray_3>
 <form medthod=post name=fr_3 id=fr_3>
  <input type=text name=a> <input type=text name=b> <input type=text name=c>
  <input type=submit name=b_3 value=ok>
 </form>
</li>
 .etc .... > 100
```

Comment: Not with CSS - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with pure css, you'll need to use javascript / jQuery:

```
$("input[type='text']").focus(function(){
    $("li").removeClass("background");
    $(this).closest("li").addClass("background");
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/HF5Tx/

Comment: I can see your jsfiddle working just fine, but I can't make my script work.

My li looks like this: #contentLeft li {
text-align:left;
list-style: none;
margin: 0 0 4px -40px;
padding: 2px;
border: #CCCCCC solid 1px;
background-color:#FFFFEF;
color:#000;
width:1160px;
}

And the code from you: 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$("input[type='text']").focus(function(){
    $("contentLeft li").removeClass("background");
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass("background");
});
</script>

Comment: In your javascript, change $("contentLeft li") to $("#contentLeft li"). And make sure you add a background class in your css, i.e: .background { background-color:red; }. I used the "background" class as an example, you can change it to "active" or "li-active", or something (in both your jQuery code and your CSS of course).

Comment: Thank you! Now the lines get red, BUT they all stay red after clicking so I can have many red lines and not only the active as in your example. Have I missed something?

Comment: Make sure you have the right selector in $("#contentLeft li").removeClass("background"). In your example you missed the "#". Make sure the list-items ("li" elements) are inside an element with the id "contentLeft". Or do $("li").removeClass("background") to target all list-items on the page.

Comment: I broke my page down in pieces and the reson it doesn't work is cause I have a table within my <li><table>...</table></li>. Can this be fixed or do I have to rebuild my hole webpage. I have 40 cols (containg text-inputs checkbox inputs) in each row so it would take a lot of work to place them all with css.
Can this script work if I click a checkbox as well as text input box?

Comment: Try changing $(this).parent().parent().addClass("background"); with $(this).closest("li").addClass("background"); If that doesn't work, please post a Fiddle of your code.

Comment: Yes, that works! Thank you. But is it possible to use checkboxes in the same function?

Comment: EDIT: I doubbled the function and put checkbox in the other and that works. Thank you very much for all your help

Comment: You're welcome :) Btw you can change $("input[type='text']") to $("input[type='text'], input[type='checkbox']") to target textfields and checkboxes, or just $("input") to target all input elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a sibling element to the input elements and make it cover the li with background color on hover.

**CSS**

```
input[type=text]:focus~div {
    background-color:red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
li {
    position:relative;
}
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/zX8tH/6/)

Comment: +1 Better to use `:focus` pseudo-class: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/zX8tH/2/

Comment: @HashemQolami yep updated..

Comment: Just make the div `z-index: -1`?

Comment: @Bergi ok got it... :)

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is no parent selector, you have a hover state on the li triggered by the hover of the children (the hover *bubbles*).

One posibility is to use that state, and if you want to avoid the change when the cursor is on the li, but not on the inputs, just disable the hover event:

CSS

```
li {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
}
li:hover {
    background-color: red;

}
input {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zX8tH/5/)

Comment: Thanks! But this only works for hoover. I need the row to stay red as long as I have the cursor in a field

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to set the background-color of the "li" when I put the cursor in on of its children inputs?

No, unfortunately the `:focus` selector does not work on the ancestors of the focused element, so you cannot detect that. `:active` would, but does only flash in the moment of the click.

The `:hover` selector (applied to the `li`) could do it, assuming you're using mouse navigation it would have a similar effect - and also help while viewing the table, not only when filling out inputs. However, it doesn't work with keyboard-based navigation.

So you can only resort to JS (using jQuery for an example, same is easily achievable with native DOM):

```
var $lis = $("li");
$lis.find("input:text").focus(function(e) {
    $lis.css("background-color", "none");
    $(this).closest("li").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Comment: Hi! I tried your suggestion but couldn't make it work

Comment: @user3214817: [Works well for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Yhu87/).

Comment: Tried again and it works but with the same problem as Leons suggest. All the lines stayes colored after click